# Need to connect HP QC from linux machine using Python script

Tags: python, linux, hp-quality-center

I want to automate my result posting stuff in QC using my Python script and that too form Linux machine.  I have a lots of examples and stuffs to connect to QC in Windows using `wincom32` module for windows Python, But in linux i am not able to find any example code. Can anyone help me in same ??

Answer (score 0):

Since the QC OTA API is a COM library (needed DLL: OTAClient.dll), I don't think it is possible to use this approach from Linux. If you use ALM11 or later, you can use the REST API. With this API it should be possible to import stuff to QC no mather which platform you're on. See [this page](http://almster.wordpress.com/category/python/) for some Python samples using the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help...
https://code.google.com/p/py-qcapi/

I was doing some work with the com32 and the QC api, I don't have it available on my phone (I'll look it up when I'm back at the office)